# CSS Estilizar input range

Tags: html, css, input, range

Preciso fazer um input range para definição de faixa etária desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pensei em fazer a barra "grande" com essa faixa fixa de 20 em 20, ou uma barra não fixa como [nesse exemplo](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range), mas sou novato e não entendo o que acontece, muito menos como alterar o modo de mostrar os valores da faixa etária. 
Alguma idéia de como fazer?

EDIT: se alguém puder me explicar o exemplo do link, agradeço muito, principalmente a estilização dele que terei que alterar se ele for usado.

Answer (score 1):

Esse é o código do site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Pelo que entendi:

```
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
```

Aqui você atribui os valores mínimo, máximo e default (valor que aparecerá quando a página for carregada, sem o usuário modificar o range)

```
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
```

Aqui está a estilização, border:0 quer dizer que não terá borda, color:#f6931f é a cor do texto e font-weight:bold aplica o efeito de negrito ao texto

Observação: esse exemplo usa css inline, o melhor seria usar css linkado recomendo que leia sobre isso