# Como dar espaço entre o valor e a margem de um campo input?

Tags: html, css

Possuo um campo `input` do tipo `text`, porém ao digitar algo nesse campo, o `value` fica encostado na borda do input, como alterar a posição do que foi digitado para ficar com uma margem da borda?

Comment: Utilize o a propriedade CSS padding no input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quem define o aspecto visual é a folha de estilos (CSS).

A margem interna numa folha de estilos é definda pela propriedade `padding`.

Estilos podem ser fornecidos "inline", por arquivos externos ou dentro de um bloco `<style>`

Veja dois exemplos inline e um usando classe:

```html
<style>
   .superborda {padding:50px}
</style>

<input type="text" style="padding:4px" value="um">
<input type="text" style="padding:5px 20px" value="dois">
<input type="text" class="superborda" value="três">
```

Links que podem ajudar:

> [Qual a diferença entre padding e margin no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189978/70)

Técnicas mais avançadas:

> [Como estilizar um input do tipo checkbox?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394303/70)

> [Como estilizar um input do tipo "file"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90179/70)

> [CSS Estilizar input range](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235648/70)

> [Como estilizar o ícone "limpar" do input type search?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206539/70)

> [Estilizar um input type='number' para trocar as setas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336061/70)

> [Como posso estilizar a seta da tag <select> no Firefox?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249449/70)

Comment: Quem é vivo....... sempre responde... :)

Comment: @Bacco obrigado

Comment: Sobre links com coisas relacionados não consigo pensar muito agora... a não ser que seja algo relacionado a user-agent talvez, ou alinhamentos direita/esquerda, input é vou não da para colocar um ::after, não se deve tirar o outline, atributos globais do input etc...Mas nada muito relacionado a espaçamento... Vou até postar uma respostinha, mas só pra constar como opção...

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas formas de fazer uma borda, sem precisar usar a borda original do input, que é colocada pelo user-agent do browser.

Vc pode customizar um `outline` para usar como borda, pois assim vc tem a propriedade `outline-offset` para controlar o afastamento da "borda" do input. Além disso vc pode usar a pseudo-classe `:focus` para deixar o `input` ainda mais customizado quando o usuário clicar nele...

Veja uns exemplos. A borda pontilhada é o que seria a borda original do `input`. O contra do `outline` é que vc não consegue controlar cada um dos lados como no `padding: 5px 10px;` da resposta do @bacco, acredito que a resposta dele pode ser mais versátil, mas vou deixar essa aqui só pra constar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
input {
    border: 1px dashed #ddd;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    outline-offset: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
input:focus {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
input:nth-child(2) {
    outline-offset: 0px;
}
input:nth-child(2):focus {
    outline-offset: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 255);
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="123">
<input type="text" value="clica aqui">
```

Comment: muito boa a dica, valeu.

Comment: @GabrielFerreira sem problemas ;)